# Exclude the environment name form pycharms iml/xml configuration to avoid commit madness

Tags: git, pycharm, anaconda

I get why it's reasonable to include pycharm files into the repository.
But is there any way to specify that the name of the used environment does not matter?
For same reason im not able to not mess it up when trying to work together with my colleges.
To be honest i don't really care how they name their environment as long as they manage to install the right packages or do i miss the point here?

Thank you all in advance :)

[very important change that must be included in the next commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CM5I.png)

Comment: Consider dropping .idea/misc.xml from VCS, some files under .idea are better not be committed

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've also considered that option but i've assumed it was recommended to include that specific files because otherwise it would already be excluded by the [template](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/pycharm) i usually use for pycharm.